# Echo a table of people - PHP, MySQL

Tags: php, html, database

I have a database table called 'partners'. I want to echo this table into a html/php table which has 5 columns id, channel, email, paypal, and network. I also wan't a form that adds new people to the table through the website.

Comment: @GoAerox you got to be more particular about the question.

Comment: Hi, yes sorry I'm not to good with questions. I'll work on it for next time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "mysql_user", "mysql_password"); //your parameters here
mysql_select_db("mydb"); //you DB name here

$q = "SELECT id, channel, email, paypal, network FROM partners;";
$result = mysql_query($q);

echo "<table>";
echo "<tr><td>id</td><td>channel</td><td>email</td><td>paypal</td><td>network </td></tr>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$row[0]."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row[1]."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row[2]."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row[3]."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row[4]."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

mysql_free_result($result);
```

Comment: Hi Cruel_Crow thanks for the quick reply, but there was a: 'Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'while' (T_WHILE), expecting ',' or ';' in public_html/dashboard/addchannel.php on line 10'

Comment: As it says - I forgot semicolons.

Comment: Sorry if I sound dumb, but where? I am not a full developer/coder. I self taught and I am in the process of creating a full dashboard from psd to html to php. :)

Comment: Line 10, as the error says. Every line in PHP must end with a semicolon. I fixed it in the answer already.